# error: no suitable method found for add(double) arr.add(root1);

Tags: java

```
int D = b*b - 4*a*c;
double root1; 
double root2;

if(D<0){
    System.out.println("Imaginary");
}
else if(D==0){
    root1=root2= Math.floor((-b)/(2*a));
}

else if(D>0){
    root1= Math.floor(((-b)+ Math.sqrt(D))/(2*a)); 
    root2= Math.floor(((-b) - Math.sqrt(D))/(2*a));   
}

ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

arr.add(root1);
arr.add(root2);

return arr;
```

```
error: no suitable method found for add(double)
    arr.add(root1);
```

How to solve this?
I don't know how to convert this in required output please help!

Comment: Why would you expect an `ArrayList<Integer>` to be able to contain `double`s? Shouldn't it be an `ArrayList<Double>` instead?

Comment: Or, if you actually need to return a list of `int`s you'll have to cast `root1` and `root2` (`arr.add((int)root1);`) but, of course, you'll lose the decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

```
double root1; 
// ...
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you try to add `root1` to `arr`, it is incompatible. A `double` cannot be added to `Integer` type.

Either change:

```
List<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Or:

```
int root1;
root1 = (int) Math.floor(((-b)+ Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a));
```